# CSS Smooth borders around two different sized boxes

Tags: html, css, border, semantic-ui

I'm wondering if this is possible to even make.
My customer want's borders like this around order confirm page.

[image]

I'm using semantic UI for this site, code for grid/segments:

```
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="eleven wide computer eleven wide tablet sixteen wide mobile column">
            <div class="ui top attached header">
                <h3>Large box</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached segment">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="five wide computer four five tablet sixteen wide mobile column">
            <div class="ui top attached header">
                <h3>Small box</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached segment">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how to make borders like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce two divs of the same size of those and give them a border and border-radius. Only problem is in the corner where both divs coincide there won't be any border-radius.

```css
.back{position:absolute;border:10px solid green;border-radius:10px;}
.front{margin:10px;position:absolute;background:white; border:1px solid black;}
.big{top:0;left:0;width:200px;height:200px;}
.small{top:0;left:200px;width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="big back"></div>
<div class="small back"></div>
<div class="big front"></div>
<div class="small front"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use box-shadow and a bit of negative margins to overlap edges:

*([This `flex` version](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mOEMzN) is inspired from http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HKEpo )*

```css
h3,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.ui.grid {
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
.ui.grid .eleven {
  flex: 11;
}
.ui.grid .five {
  flex: 5;
}
.ui.top,
.ui.bottom {
  border: 1em solid white;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px green, inset 0 0 2px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ui.top {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.ui.bottom {
  border-top: 0;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px green, 3px 3px green, inset 0 0 2px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.column + .column .ui.bottom {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px green, inset 0 0 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.column + .column .ui.bottom:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  top: 100%;
  left: -2em;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px green, -3px -3px white
}
.column + .column .ui.top {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px -3px green, -9px -3px green, inset 0 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="eleven wide computer eleven wide tablet sixteen wide mobile column">
    <div class="ui top attached header">
      <h3>Large box</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached segment">
      <p>Hinc ceteri particulas arripere conati suam quisque videro voluit afferre sententiam. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huius, Lyco, oratione locuples,
        rebus ipsis ielunior. Pudebit te, inquam, illius tabulae, quam Cleanthes sane commode verbis depingere solebat. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. Nisi autem rerum natura perspecta erit, nullo modo poterimus sensuum
        iudicia defendere. Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Gerendus est mos, modo recte sentiat.</p>
      <p>Hinc ceteri particulas arripere conati suam quisque videro voluit afferre sententiam. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huius, Lyco, oratione locuples,
        rebus ipsis ielunior. Pudebit te, inquam, illius tabulae, quam Cleanthes sane commode verbis depingere solebat. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. Nisi autem rerum natura perspecta erit, nullo modo poterimus sensuum
        iudicia defendere. Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Gerendus est mos, modo recte sentiat.</p>
      <p>Hinc ceteri particulas arripere conati suam quisque videro voluit afferre sententiam. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huius, Lyco, oratione locuples,
        rebus ipsis ielunior. Pudebit te, inquam, illius tabulae, quam Cleanthes sane commode verbis depingere solebat. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. Nisi autem rerum natura perspecta erit, nullo modo poterimus sensuum
        iudicia defendere. Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Gerendus est mos, modo recte sentiat.</p>
      <p>Hinc ceteri particulas arripere conati suam quisque videro voluit afferre sententiam. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huius, Lyco, oratione locuples,
        rebus ipsis ielunior. Pudebit te, inquam, illius tabulae, quam Cleanthes sane commode verbis depingere solebat. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. Nisi autem rerum natura perspecta erit, nullo modo poterimus sensuum
        iudicia defendere. Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Gerendus est mos, modo recte sentiat.</p>
      <p>Hinc ceteri particulas arripere conati suam quisque videro voluit afferre sententiam. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huius, Lyco, oratione locuples,
        rebus ipsis ielunior. Pudebit te, inquam, illius tabulae, quam Cleanthes sane commode verbis depingere solebat. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. Nisi autem rerum natura perspecta erit, nullo modo poterimus sensuum
        iudicia defendere. Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Gerendus est mos, modo recte sentiat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="five wide computer four five tablet sixteen wide mobile column">
    <div class="ui top attached header">
      <h3>Small box</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached segment">
      <p>Hinc ceteri particulas arripere conati suam quisque videro voluit afferre sententiam. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huius, Lyco, oratione locuples,
        rebus ipsis ielunior. Pudebit te, inquam, illius tabulae, quam Cleanthes sane commode verbis depingere solebat. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. Nisi autem rerum natura perspecta erit, nullo modo poterimus sensuum
        iudicia defendere. Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Gerendus est mos, modo recte sentiat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

note this works as long as column 2 is shorter :(